# trying to append a bootstrap panel into the DOM

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

After clicking a button (#music) I'm trying to add a bootstrap panel with some text.  Instead, what I get is a blank panel, and the text by underneath it.  Besides that, this code works fine.

```
$("#music").on("click", function() {
$(".jumbotron").hide();
picture.attr("src", "img/rickenbacker.jpg");
var panel= $("<div>").addClass("panel panel-default");
var panelbody = $("<div>").addClass("panel-body");
var textp =$("<p>").append("this is just a test");

$(".col-md-8").append(panel).append(panelbody).append(textp);
});
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably need to do is this:

```
$(panelbody).append(textp);
$(panel).append(panelbody);
$(".col-md-8").append(panel);
```

Use this instead of:

```
$(".col-md-8").append(panel).append(panelbody).append(textp);
```

Your code is not working because jQuery is returning the original element in each case (i.e. col-md-8)